# How to properly resize voronoi in a reponsive chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, voronoi

I have a responsive line chart made with d3, but have problem resizing the voronoi used for hover state. I suspect I don't refer to it the right way...

I added the voronoi here:

```
var voronoiGroup = svg.append("g")

.attr("class", "voronoi");

voronoiGroup.selectAll("line")
.data(voronoi(d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return xScale(d.date) + "," + yScale(d.value); })
      .rollup(function(v) { return v[0]; })
      .entries(d3.merge(ranksFiltered.map(function(d) { return d.values;})))
      .map(function(d) { return d.values; })))
.enter()

.append("path")
   .attr("id", "cells")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z"; })
  .datum(function(d) { return d.point; });
```

and in my resize function, I attempt to redraw it:

```
  svg.select("#cells path")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z"; })
  .datum(function(d) { return d.point; });;
```

If someone wants to take a stab at it, there's a plunk here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Jj4QpF1bqK901WalNMmR

Thanks for you time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Voronoi Geom is calculating pixel positions in relation to the [clipExtent](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Voronoi-Geom#clipExtent).  Since you are changing your width (the clipextent), you need to rerun the calculations.  This is one of the few times with `d3` that I'd recommend just remove the paths under your voronoi group and re-adding them:

```
        voronoi.clipExtent([[0, -10], [width+10, height]]);
        voronoiGroup.selectAll("path").remove();

        voronoiGroup.selectAll("cells")
          .data(voronoi(vd))
          .enter()
          .append("path")
          .attr("class", "cells")
          .attr("d", function(d) { return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z"; })
          .datum(function(d) { return d.point; })
          .attr("stroke", "red")
          .on("mouseover", mouseover)
          .on("mouseout", mouseout);
```

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ayaz2vzIzG8D570u0f0E?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you so much! However, there are still some remaining problems. Now the chart line and area are not being resized properly when you change the window size. Also the hover text doesnt appear anymore, I guess the function is not valid anymore after the voronoi paths are removed and re-added. I would have think this function would remain and could be re-used...
Also not visible in the plunker interface, but it looks like now the axis are being duplicated at every resize, resulting in the horizontal ticks to look thicker/wrong. 
Any idea how to fix that? Again thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Actually the Y axis ticks look fine,but I see the x axis doesnt recalculate ticks frequency, resulting in text collision

Comment: @CapivaraGraphics, the `mouseover`, `mouseout` functions are out of scope in the resize function.  I increased their scope to their parent level and all should be ok.  Updated code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ayaz2vzIzG8D570u0f0E?p=preview).  Sorry about that.

Comment: Amazing, works great. I am clearly over my head with this thing ;)